# What are Fan Missions?

Tags: system-shock-2

When launching System Shock 2 through Steam, I get two options:

[image: • Play System Shock 2 • Launch with Fan Missions]

What are Fan Missions?  I assume they are additions to the game made by fans, but will they affect the main story or are they like bonus levels?  If they are bonus levels, would the second option not allow playing the base game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fan missions are custom scenarios built with ShockEd, System Shock 2's scenario editor. They are entirely separate from the main game, similar to how Minerva is a Half-Life 2 mod that's launched separately from Half-Life 2. You'd have to relaunch in order to play the main game.

ShockEd as well as tutorials and other resources are available for [download](http://www.sshock2.com/shocked/default.asp) from the [main fan site](http://www.sshock2.com/default.asp). [Fan Missions](http://www.sshock2.com/shocked/Missions.asp) can be found there as well.